# wbadmin: Does -allCritical include the system state?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, backup, windows-server-2012-r2, wbadmin

From the Windows IT Pro Center [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wbadmin-start-backup) of the `wbadmin start backup` option `-allCritical` (italics by me):

> Specifies that all critical volumes (volumes that contain operating
>   *system's state*) be included in the backups. This parameter is useful
>   if you are creating a backup for bare metal recovery. It should be
>   used only when **-backupTarget** is specified, otherwise the command will
>   fail. Can be used with the **-include** option. Tip: The target volume for
>   a critical-volume backup can be a local drive, but it cannot be any of
>   the volumes that are included in the backup.

Then there is the option `-systemState`:

> For Windows°7 [sic] and Windows Server 2008 R2 and later, creates a backup
>   that includes the system state in addition to any other items that you
>   specified with the -include parameter. The system state contains boot
>   files (Boot.ini, NDTLDR, NTDetect.com), the Windows Registry including
>   COM settings, the SYSVOL (Group Policies and Logon Scripts), the
>   Active Directory and NTDS.DIT on Domain Controllers and, if the
>   certificates service is installed, the Certificate Store. If your
>   server has the Web server role installed, the IIS Metadirectory will
>   be included. If the server is part of a cluster, Cluster Service
>   information will also be included.

*Am I right to assume that `-allCritical` includes the data referenced by the option `-systemState`?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, it does!** As you can read on [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/filecab/2009/05/04/deciding-between-system-state-backup-and-allcritical-backup-in-windows-server-2008/) Technet blog post by MSFT [Jose Barreto](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/profile/JoseBarreto).

> Q) If I take an Allcritical Backup, can I perform a System State Recovery and create a IFM dump of my AD server with it?
>
> A) Yes you can! There is no difference between a SSR or a IFM dump done from Allcritical or System State Backup. Allcritical Backup is basically a superset of a System State Backup.

Doing an **Allcritical** will be the smart move in most scenarios, since it **will take less time** in most cases, unless you have many non-OS-critical files on your server.

According to the same post there will be less IO and overhead:

> Q) I am seeing that Allcritical backups are pretty faster than SSB’s
> why is that?
>
> A) This is because Allcritical backups back up volumes at Block level
> , so the backing up happens below the file system layer and hence are
> faster than SSB’s which need to first identify all files to be backed
> up and then back them up individually one by one. This again is not
> true always , if for example you have a 150 GB hard disk with 10 GB
> system data another 130 GB of other data like photos , videos etc then
> the Allcritical backup will certainly take longer time for completion
> than SSB since the amount of data is much more.